# How does C compiler `-O0` make code go so crazy?

Tags: c, gcc

Please take a look at: https://godbolt.org/z/WGBP8D

Code:

```
    size_t n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    fprintf(stderr, "(1 <= %d) == %d\n", n, 1 <= n);
    fprintf(stderr, "(%d <= 1000) == %d\n", n, n <= 1000);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", 2 <= 1000);
    ASSERT(1 <= n && n <= 1000);
```

Input is set to be:

```
2
1
2
```

Output:

```
(1 <= 2) == 1
(2 <= 1000) == 0
1
Assertion failed: 1 <= n && n <= 1000
```

Commenting out further part of code changes behavior of the snippet above. How is that?

Funny thing is, any optimization enabled (`-O1`) works nicely, but no optimization (`-O0` or not specified) makes it... Well, I don't even know how to understand it.

Comment: You're telling `scanf()` and `printf()` that `n` is an int, when it's a `size_t`, which is larger than an int on the x86-64 platform... undefined behavior rears its head once more. Turn on compiler warnings and use the right format for `size_t`.

Comment: @Shawn How does it work with `-o1` then? Shouldn't it be the same process in-depth?

Comment: @PsychoX maybe, maybe not, it's undefined behaviour. That includes "apparently working fine"

Comment: When you get different results depending on optimization level you KNOW you've done something wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scanf` is affecting just the bottom 32 bits of the 64-bit **n**. `printf` is displaying just that bottom 32 bits, as well, but with some optimisation, there's something in the upper 32-bits, making **n** bigger than 1000, hence this line of output:

```
(2 <= 1000) == 0
```

Using `-Wall` will probably warn you of the problem.